# What are the ways that change in capacitance can be measured?

Tags: capacitor

What are some ways that capacitance change can be measured e.g in a capacitive pressure sensor

Comment: May find this answer useful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/507771/152903

Comment: RC Astable frequency measurement with CMOS Schmitt inverter

Answer (score 1):

An AC bridge is one way, and is capable of exquisite sensitivity in displacement measurement (sub-nanometer). Differential capacitance is preferable. For low performance, the other two legs of the bridge can be resistors.

Answer (score 1):

a classical method would be to use the capacitor as part of an oscillator, and simply count the oscillation it does in a fixed time.

If your "change" is between two capacitors at the same time, you can use one as reference for the other; build two oscillators and either

- do the counting approach above ("in 1000 oscillations of the C1 oscillator, C2 only did 900" means C2 has a larger value), which is extremely easy if you have a microcontroller with two counter units, or
- work with a phase detector as used in PLLs, e.g. the

  1. classical XOR detector, (gives you a pulse of length proportional to the phase difference), then
  2. low pass filter the result (gives you a voltage proportional to the phase difference),
  3. form the derivative of the result (frequency is the derivate of phase over time), e.g. using an opamp differentiator or simply a CR high-pass filter, depending on how much linearity you need (both will give you a voltage monotonous to frequency difference, but only a true derivative will be *proportional* to the frequency difference. However, your oscillator might not have a frequency perfectly proportional to your capacity, so there's a chance to optimize things)

Other ways to compare these capacitors would include building two RC-low-pass filters with them, and feeding them both a sine of the same frequency, then subtract the resulting voltages. The voltage difference is proportional to the amplitude attenuation difference at that frequency.

There's many methods of measuring capacitance, but these are the most common ones (for others, search the site, there's plenty of questions about it), and I posted this here instead of linking to a duplicate question, because you seem to be interested in *relative* capacitance.